# Extract return types of function and filter by property name in typescript

Tags: typescript, return-type, conditional-types

I am trying to identify return types of functions that have a specific property name, the aim is to filter out any function that doesn't have this return property name.

To illustrate, let say we have the following object of functions:

```
export const StorageActions = {
  addFile: () => ({ type: 'ADD_FILE' }),
  deleteFile: () => {
    return () => {
      return null;
    };
  },
};
type StorageActionsTypes = typeof StorageActions;
```

With the help of ReturnType, I can see which function does have return property name of 'type':

[image]

To validate the functions that do have return property name of 'type', I am 
doing as follow:

```
type filteredActions = { [K in keyof StorageActionsTypes]: 
    keyof ReturnType<StorageActionsTypes[K]> extends ('type') ?  'valid' : 'invalid'};
```

but the result is unexpected:

[image]

it should be:

```
interface filteredActions {
  addFile: 'valid';
  deleteFile: 'invalid';
}
```

Am I using the 'extends' incorrectly? what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please clarify your question. If this is about typescript compile time typing rather than JavaScript runtime evaluation, please indicate that. Also, if that is the case, remove the JavaScript Tag from your question. Thanks.

Comment: thanks for the clarification.

Comment: removed the javascript tag, it was misleading, sorry.

Comment: No big deal. Glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your interpretation of `never`. Never as described in the [PR](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8652) :

> `never` is a subtype of and assignable to every type.

This means that this type `type y = never extends 's' ? 'Y' : 'N'` will be `'Y'` since `never` is a subtype of `'s'`.

The simple solution here is not to use `keyof` (which for functions will return `never` hence the problem above)

```
export const StorageActions = {
    addFile: () => ({ type: 'ADD_FILE' }),
    deleteFile: () => {
        return () => {
            return null;
        };
    },
};

type StorageActionsTypes = typeof StorageActions
type filteredActions = {
    [K in keyof StorageActionsTypes]:
        ReturnType<StorageActionsTypes[K]> extends { type: any } ? 'valid' : 'invalid'
}; // now  { addFile: "valid"; deleteFile: "invalid"; }
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what I want, didn't know about 'never', thanks for clarifications.